Node-gyp prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild falling with python 3.12
I'm working on a React Native Expo project, and I'm encountering an error from node-gyp when I try to install or build dependencies. The error occurs because node-gyp expects Python 3.10, but my system has Python 3.12 installed. I've found that using Python 3.10 resolves the issue, but this isn't ideal because my Android builds require Python 3.12.
Currently, I'm using Node.js v18 with node-gyp 8. Is there a proper solution to this problem? The error sometimes occurs with packages like snappy and node-sass. Any help would be appreciated
/Users/XXX/Documents/my-project/node_modules/snappy: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
Arguments: 
Directory: Users/XXX/Documents/my-project/node_modules/snappy

I'm using macOS Sonoma(14) in Apple Silicon

npm config set python=/full/path/to/older/python3.10 or export npm_config_python=full/path/to/older/python3.10 .. these are mentioned in node-gyp  readme at https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#configuration  .. homebrew can install multiple python versions just fine but you need to keep those separated in your shell's PATH ..

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp?tab=readme-ov-file#installation

Python 3.12 requires node-gyp >= 10
